# Using HTTPClient in Grails 2.4

Tags: java, grails, apache-httpclient-4.x

New to Grails and trying to use HttpClient from apache to use it on integration tests ... so i put it's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'
    build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.2'
    build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'
    test 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.2'
    test 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'
}
```

in build.config and expected to be able to use it on tests like

```
class MyControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    @Test
    void testApacheHttpClient() {
        def client = new HttpClient()
    }
}
```

However i cannot make it work because grails is unable to resolve any class.

I've tried with manual import without success.

What i am doing wrong?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `Commons HttpClient` as a dependency.

You should add this to your dependencies:

```
test 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
```

Also be sure to import the correct class on your source code:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
```

Comment: i see now that is the usual silly thing but still i spend quite some hours trying to figure it out. The usual thing ... thanks.